# Tensorflow maximum of three functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I have a loss function that goes like this: max(f1,f2,f3) where f1,f2, and f3 are functions. How do I implement this in tensorflow v1.15.0? The function `tf.maximum` only takes two arguments, so I cannot pass all three functions at once.

Is writing nested max functions like `tf.maximum(tf.maximum(f1,f2),f3)` the correct way to proceed?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reduce_max`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_max) instead of `maximum`, for example `tf.reduce_max([1, 2, 3])`, if you want to stick with tensorflow.

Comment: Thank you. I need to reduce the absolute maximum. Is it correct to write tf.reduce_max(tf.abs([1,2,3]))?

Comment: The function ```tf.reduce_max([f1,f2,f3])``` performs drastically poorer than ```tf.maximum(tf.maximum(f1,f2),f3)``` in minimizing the error. Any idea why?

Comment: Well, I expected them to perform similarly, could you try using [`np.max()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html) instead of `tf.reduce_max()`?

Comment: I am passing tensorflow placeholders inside tf.reduce_max so I cannot really use numpy.max().

Comment: `timeit_reduce_max = 28.74s; timeit_numpy = 10.99s, timeit_your_proposal = 25.51s` This is what I get when running each function million times, I'm not sure if I understand why can't you use numpy, but if you will always have only those three values your approach seems to be good enough.